# Excel: Pasting values clobbers table (i.e. list) object

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a formally defined table (also known as a list object) in Excel.  I have copied old versions of that table to other areas in the worksheet.  But they are just for reference.  There is only one main table, and it is named.

When I want to copy values from some of the reference tables, i.e., paste values into the main table (of exactly the same size), for some reasons, that makes the main table become just a normal range.  I conclude this by noting that Table Tools disappears from the ribbon.  As well, the table format is gone (I have a custom table style with visible borders, and the borders disappear).

Since I'm pasting as values, I did not expect this kind of destructive clobbering to occur.  What could be causing this, and what can I do to avoid this?

I am using Excel 2010 in a computationally locked down environment.  Custom addons and tools are not within the realm of possibility here.

AFTERNOTE: It only seems to be a problem if the source range is a table.  So one work-around may be to convert the reference table to a normal range before copying and pasting its values into the main (destination) table.